# Validate a Swagger 2.0 spec in Maven build?

Tags: rest, maven, swagger, swagger-editor

I am following a design-first approach to building a REST API, on a Java/Spring MVC stack.

I have a hand-written Swagger schema that I want to validate in my Maven build, and I want that build to fail if the schema doesn't conform to the Swagger schema specification.

I've tried doing this by using `swagger-codegen` to generate some static documentation; but 1) it's not catching errors that `swagger-editor` catches; and 2) the output isn't great (but that's beside the point ;-)).

Has anybody solved this problem satisfactorily themselves?

Comment: Is that hand-written Swagger document going to change a lot? Why can't you just validate it in swagger-editor once you modify it?

Comment: The thought had crossed my mind, but yes, it will change, so I want a guarantee that it cannot break, by enforcing checks in the build.

Here's my general approach: http://bjf-codebrown.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/contract-first-restful-api-development.html

Comment: Nice article! I wanted to suggest `assertj-swagger` but saw it is already mentioned in your article.

Comment: @NavidShakibapour : thanks! Additionally, I've contributed to `assertj-swagger` to address some issues I was having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extra step in your Maven build system to validate the Swagger document against the [Swagger 2.0 Schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json).

I created a sample Maven project that validates the swagger JSON documents under `/src/main/resources/swagger`.

You can clone the project here: https://github.com/navidsh/maven.swagger.validator